# Copy artifact within a jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins pipeline job that archives an Artifact in its first phase, I then need to copy that Artifact in another stage of the pipeline build

```
node {
  stage 'Stage 1 of build'
  // Run tests, if successful archive the artifact
  archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'build/test.js', excludes: null
 stage 'Stage 2 of build'
 // want to copy artifact from stage 1 of the build
 step([$class: 'CopyArtifact', filter: 'build/test.js', fingerprintArtifacts: true, flatten: true, projectName: 'echo-develop-js-pipeline', selector: [$class: 'WorkspaceSelector'], target: './client/public/vendor/echo/'])
}
```

With this I get a `unable to find a build for artifact copy`

When the artifact is created it is saved here:

```
http://localhost:8181/view/Echo JS Develop/job/echo-develop-js-pipeline/233/artifact/build/test.js
```

How do I access the created artifact from within a pipeline job?

Answer (score 12):

I needed this recently, and none of the other solutions here did exactly what I wanted, because I **need to use multiple parameter filters** for my selection. Here's what I did using the "*Run Selector Plugin*" in addition to the direct calling of the "*Copy Artifact Plugin*":

Step One: Select the build number you need.

```
prereq_build = selectRun filter: parameters("TARGET_OS=${TARGET_OS},GIT_BRANCH_NAME=${GIT_BRANCH_NAME}"), job: 'prereq_rpms', selector: status('STABLE'), verbose: true
```

Step Two: Copy (**updated 2017-11: Native pipeline support now!**).

```
        copyArtifacts(
          projectName: 'prereq_rpms',
          filter: '**/*.rpm',
          fingerprintArtifacts: true,
          target: 'prereq',
          flatten: true,
          selector: specific(prereq_build.getId())
        )
```

Comment: `Step Two: Copy (updated 2017-11: Native pipeline support now!).`... Finally they have native support for this central functionallity!

Comment: Yes, IMHO this falls in the "should be a core function" bin, and not a plugin.

Answer (score 7):

Figured this one out, so using the var ${BUILD_NUMBER} you can access artifacts un the current pipeline

```
step([$class: 'CopyArtifact', filter: 'build/test.js', fingerprintArtifacts: true, flatten: true, projectName: 'echo-develop-js-pipeline', selector: [$class: 'SpecificBuildSelector', buildNumber: '${BUILD_NUMBER}'], target: './client/public/vendor/echo/'])
```

Comment: There's (finally) native pipeline support and it's nearly a drop-in replacement, but with a cleaner selection interface. I've updated my answer as well to show it.

Comment: How can I figure out the triggered build number? I can't take last (successful or last with artifacts) because of multiple instances of the current job trigger different downstream jobs (e.g. with different parameters).

Answer (score 3):

In pipeline plugin, there is a new feature called 'stash', 'unstash' instead of artifacts.

Artifact: Archives are designed for longer term file storage (e.g., intermediate binaries from your builds). Artifact requires more storage space and resource management.

Stash: Saves a set of files and use later in the same build, generally on another node/workspace. stash and unstash steps are designed for use with small files. Stash/unstash can be used inside a pipeline with just assigning a name to the stash & works only locally.

Here is a good example for stash/unstash: [Tutorial](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/examples/)

Comment: `stash` also says to limit the size and is not a one-size-fits all. Within a single job, `archive`/`unarchive` is better.